# Simplifying and interpreting a RootSum output

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

[image]

I am trying to compute this integral with a parameter `s`. How I can simplify the output expression containing `Rootsum`, `#` and `&` ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please show us the code text, rather than the screenshot of code.

Comment: `RootSum` might be the simplest result; you can consult the docs, where it tells you that `Normal` converts it to a more traditional form. (Also, one usually has greater success with `DSolve`, an *exact* solver, by giving it exact input; that is, using exact coefficients instead of approximate floating-point numbers like `2.43902`. Using a decimal point in a numeric expression automatically makes it a floating-point number.)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the integral like follows:

```
res = Integrate[(s^(-1) + a*x^2)/(s^(-1) + a*x^2 + x^3), x]

(* RootSum[1+a*s*#1^2+s*#1^3 &,(Log[x-#1]+
a*s*Log[x-#1]*#1^2)/(2*a*#1+3*#1^2)&]/s *)
```

Check the result:

```
FullSimplify[D[res, x]]

(* (1 + a*s*x^2)/(1 + s*x^2*(a + x)) *)
```

and plot it for some parameter value:

```
s = 0.7; a = 2.43902; Plot[{NIntegrate[(s^(-1) + 
a*x^2)/(s^(-1) + a*x^2 + x^3), {x, 0, t}], 
(res /. x -> t) - (res /.    x -> 0)}, {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image]

The result res looks quite messy, hence the rootsum expression.

```
(*   s =. ; a =.; Simplify[ToRadicals[res]]
(2*(9 + a*
   s*(-a + (a^2*
         s)/(-((27*s^2)/2) - 
          a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
          3) + 
              (-((27*s^2)/2) - 
          a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3)/
       s)^2)*
    Log[(1/
    3)*(a - (a^2*
       s)/(-((27*s^2)/2) - 
        a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
        3) - 
           (-((27*s^2)/2) - 
        a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3)/
     s + 3*x)])/
 (3*s*(2*
   a^2 + (2*a^4*
     s^2)/(-((27*s^2)/2) - 
      a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) + 
       (2^(1/3)*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
        3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3))/s^2)) - 
(2*(2*2^(2/3)*(1 - I*Sqrt[3])*a^5*s^4 - 
  12*s*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
      3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) - 
       
  4*a^3*s^2*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
      3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) - 
  2*I*(-I + Sqrt[3])*a^4*s^3*
         (-54*s^2 - 4*a^3*s^3 + 
      6*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3) - 
  2*2^(2/3)*a^2*
   s*(9*I*(I + Sqrt[3])*s^2 + (-3*I + Sqrt[3])*
      Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)]) + 
       
  a*(-54*s^2 - 4*a^3*s^3 + 6*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
      3)*((-9 - 9*I*Sqrt[3])*s^2 + (3*I + Sqrt[3])*
      Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)]))*
    Log[(1/
    12)*(4*a + (2*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a^2*
       s)/(-((27*s^2)/2) - 
        a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
        3) + 
           (2^(2/3)*(1 - 
         I*Sqrt[3])*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
          3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3))/s + 12*x)])/
 (-4*2^(2/3)*a^4*s^4 + 4*I*2^(2/3)*Sqrt[3]*a^4*s^4 + 
8*a^2*s^2*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) - 
    2*2^(1/3)*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(4/3) - 
2*I*2^(1/3)*
 Sqrt[3]*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^
        (4/3)) - (2*(2*2^(2/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*a^5*s^4 - 
  12*s*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
      3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) - 
       
  4*a^3*s^2*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
      3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) + 
  2*I*(I + Sqrt[3])*a^4*s^3*
         (-54*s^2 - 4*a^3*s^3 + 
      6*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3) + 
  a*(-54*s^2 - 4*a^3*s^3 + 6*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
      3)*
         (9*I*(I + Sqrt[3])*s^2 + (-3*I + Sqrt[3])*
      Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)]) - 
  2*2^(2/3)*a^2*
   s*((-9 - 9*I*Sqrt[3])*s^2 + (3*I + Sqrt[3])*
      Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)]))*
    Log[(1/
    12)*(4*a + (2*(1 - I*Sqrt[3])*a^2*
       s)/(-((27*s^2)/2) - 
        a^3*s^3 + (3/2)*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/
        3) + 
           (2^(2/3)*(1 + 
         I*Sqrt[3])*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
          3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(1/3))/s + 12*x)])/
 (-4*2^(2/3)*a^4*s^4 - 4*I*2^(2/3)*Sqrt[3]*a^4*s^4 + 
8*a^2*s^2*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(2/3) - 
    2*2^(1/3)*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^(4/3) + 
2*I*2^(1/3)*
 Sqrt[3]*(-27*s^2 - 2*a^3*s^3 + 
    3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[s^4*(27 + 4*a^3*s)])^
        (4/3)) *)
```

Comment: Initially thank you very much for your answer! After typing these inputs I get the output of: 

(1 + a s x^2)/(1 + s x^2 (a + x))

Is that the solution to the initial integral? 

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Pavlos No, the result of Simplify[ToRadicals[res]] above gives the integral as a quite lengthy expression that I was not able to simplify further.

Comment: Thank you.

1. Is there any way to simplify it further because I want this solution with a=2.43902 to be equal to another equation in order to find the value of s.
2. What the capital I stands for in the solution?

Comment: @Pavlos 1. Because the indefinite integral is only defined up to a constant you'll have to define the limits of your integration first. Then plot res(highlimit)-res(lowlimit) as a function of s to see where the plotline meets your 'another equation's graph to get the value of s. 2. The letter I denotes the imaginary unit whose square is -1.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really tough construct to work with just starting out. `RootSum` basically means "sum the second expression in the construct with the roots of the first expression" but the format is in the form of a pure function with # and & constructs.

First though learn to cut and paste code here.  Select the code in your notebook, then Ctrl/C to copy it.  Then paste it here in your edit window.  Then select it again in the edit window then select the {} icon in the edit menu which then places the code in a code block like this:

```
mySol = u /. 
  DSolve[u'[x] == (s^-1 + 2.43902 x^2)/(s^-1 + 2.43902 x^2 + x^3), u, 
    x][[1, 1]]
mySol[2.5] /. {s -> 1, C[1] -> 2}

Plot[mySol[x] /. {s -> 1, C[1] -> 2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Nice!  Notice how `DSolve` returns a Function object which in this case has parameter s and $c_1$ which is just a C[1] variable name.  The function above is then mySol[x] with parameters s and C[1] which I just choose some values with the rule constructs s->1, C[1]->2 or anything else you wish to use.

Now just copy and paste that code into your notebook to run it.